# Can't connect to local SQL Server Express DB as a datasource

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-express

I've created a new DB on my local PC in SQL Server 2012 Express (also installed locally), through Visual Studio's SQL Server Object Explorer window. I don't really know anything about SQL Server but I can see that `.MDF` and `.LDF` files are created.

I want to add a connection to this DB through "add Data Source" but if I try to connect using the DB name, I get this error:

[image]

And if I try to connect by selecting the MDF file I get this error:

[image]

How VS and SQL Server are interacting is not clear to me - is it telling me I cannot open the `.MDF` file because it's already open *by SQL Server*? Should I even be connecting to the file, or to the DB name?

I *think* SQL Server is actually running since the DB shows up in VS but as I'm new to it, I'm not certain... here's what the Configuration tool shows:

[image]

Comment: you should be accessing the SQL Server Express on port 1433 and not access the mdf file directly. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: That's _a_ way according to the article, not the _only way. ... why _do_ they allow file-based access? It's like a throw-back to using MSAccess?

Comment: its no throw-back to MSAccess. LocalDB is ideal if you dont want to install sql server but do want a database with triggers, stored procs, views, etc everything acces does not have.

Comment: Ah, so that way I wouldn't actually need to install MSSQL(Express) locally _at all_? This seems like a different topic I should look into although how I create an MDF without using MSSQL confuses me!

Comment: If you create your database **on the server** (as you should - SQL Server after all **IS** a server-based system), then the SQL Server engine will create an `.mdf` (and a `.ldf`- but no `.sdf` - that' SQL Server **Compact Edition**) and the SQL Server **engine** will handle all interactions with those files. You just **connect** to the SQL Server instance, ask for your database, and work with it - **no fiddling around** with disk files or anything!

Comment: @GuidoG: `LocalDB` ***is*** a programmer-oriented version of SQL Server **Express** - it ***IS*** SQL Server .....

Comment: @marc_s I think that is what I've done. No toolset for actually interacting with MSSQL seemed to be installed  so I used VS but I think it's the same thing. And yes, it was LDF not SDF I'll correct.

Comment: If you want to connect to the locally installed SQL Server Express, you need to use `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` as the server/instance name, too - not the 127.0.0.1 IP address...

Comment: @marc_s exactly, it is sql server that is what i am saying. You just dont need to install the service, only a localdb driver that you can download for free from microsoft. The driver can even be installed silent by your application so the user has to do nothing at all to get it working